# Prepare MacBook for sale when OS X Lion reinstall requires Apple ID

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I'm going to sell my Macbook Pro.

When I reinstall OS X Lion, I have to enter my own Apple ID. Another Apple ID won't work, I get message "This item is temporarily unavailable".

How can I deassociate my Apple ID with this computer so that the next owner will be able to reinstall the OS with their own apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to appleid.apple.com
2. Log in using your Apple ID and password.
3. Scroll down to "Devices."
4. Click on the name of the Macbook Pro.
5. A small window will open; click on "Remove."

You may also want to read Apple's advice on [What to do before you sell or give away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065).

Comment: Thanks. Strangely, I don't see the Macbook listed under devices.

Comment: That's mysterious. If the previous OS is still available on the Macbook, try iTunes > Account > Authorizations > Deauthorize This Computer.

Comment: I have deauthorized it. Guess that's why it doesn't show up under devices? But the system still prompts me for apple id and password when I reinstall os.

Comment: If the prompt appears only as the installer begins the new installation, you might consider reformatting the HD. If you're working from an installer on separate media (not from the recovery partition of the HD), the installer screen that first appears should allow you to select Disk Utility to reformat the drive; this selection may appear on the screen or within one of the Menu Bar menus. Beyond that, or replacing the HD, I'm out of ideas.